# Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am refreshing my Spring skills using SpringBoot.  I have update the libraries to the latest versions.  When I point my browser to the application, I get the below error:

[image]

This is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/readingList")
public class ReadingListController {

private static final String reader = "russ";

private ReadingListRepository readingListRepository;

@Autowired
public ReadingListController(ReadingListRepository readingListRepository){
    this.readingListRepository = readingListRepository;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/{reader})", method={RequestMethod.GET})
public String readersBooks(@PathVariable("reader") String reader, Model model){
    List<Book> readingList = readingListRepository.findByReader(reader);
    if(readingList != null){
        model.addAttribute("books", readingList);
    }
    return "readingList";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/{reader}", method={RequestMethod.POST})
public String addToReadingList(@PathVariable("reader") String reader, Book book){
    book.setReader(reader);
    readingListRepository.save(book);
    return "redirect:/{reader}";
}
```

}

The tomcat logs looks like this:

[image: Log file]

Any suggestions or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Russ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just syntax error.

remove `)` in `value="/{reader})"`.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I need to get my glasses checked.  ;-)